# Missing Create Task Button in VSTS as Stakeholder

Tags: azure-devops

As Stakeholder I can create a workitem with the dropdown, but i miss the create button in the work item tree:

[View as Member](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f9WW.png)

[View as Stakeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S24zv.png)

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's the expected behavior for a Stakeholder.

You can change the Access level to **Basic** for the user, or as a workaround, you can create a **Task** and link the User Story as **Parent**.

**Work** --> **New Work Item** --> **Task** --> **Related Work** --> **Add link** --> **Existing Item** --> Link Type: **Parent**  --> Enter the User Story **ID** --> **OK**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping there was a shorter way for a stakeholder.